# Google sheets calculate the amount to be invested per month to generate an amount desired using compound interest

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I want to generate $100,000 over 5 years at 9% interest compounding yearly.

Is there a function or formula that will let me calculate the amount to be invested per month to reach that goal in that period of time?

I looked into the financial functions here, [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093159?hl=en&ref_topic=3105398) one looked similar but doesnt do what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command [`PMT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093185?hl=en) can be used for this. Specifically,

```
=PMT(0.09, 5, 0, -100000)
```

returns $16,709.25. I checked that the amount is correct:

- $16,709.25 after 1 year (investment only)
- $34,922.32 after 2 years (investment + 9% interest on 16,709.25)
- $54,774.58 after 3 years (investment + 9% interest on 34,922.32)
- $76,413.54 after 4 years
- $100,000.00 after 5 years